# Question about a QList<QStringList> in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4, nokia, qstring

I'm using Qt 4.5 and im working with a `QList<QStringList>` which is a list of string list.

Now I want to replace one string inside one stringList but with it seems unusual to type.  I have found the following way of doing it and was wondering if it is ok:

```
QList <QStringList> pDataList;

pDataList[listIndex].replace(QStringIndex, newString);
```

Now, I'm not worried about the syntax, but I want to know if `pDataList`'s pointers is adjascent in memory so that it is okay to use `[]`. Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue of `pDataList`'s elements being adjacent in memory is not related to the question of whether it is ok to use `operator[]`.

In general, `QList<>` does not guarantee that its elements are adjacent in memory, but it does overload `operator[]` to give you the element you're looking for nonetheless.

The only thing you need to worry about when doing something like this is to make sure that `(pDataList.size() < listIndex)`. otherwise, you'll be indexing elements not in the list, triggering an exception in debug or undefined behavior in release.

Comment: I think you mean `pDataList.size() > listIndex`